# Debug antlr in vscode with launch.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, antlr, antlr4

I'm using vscode 1.84.0 and ANTLR4 grammar syntax support v2.4.2.
I also installed Debugger for Java v0.55.0 and I have Java-11 installed.

The tokens, lexer and listener files are created.
Now I want to launch a debug session using the launch.json to parse my file and debug.
My launch.json looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "configurations": 
    [
        
        
        {
        "name": "mmmTable",
        "type": "antlr-debug",
        "request": "launch",
        "input": "inputs/mmm_Table.txt",
        "grammar": "grammars/mmmTable.g4",
        "startRule": "mmm_table",
        "printParseTree": true,
        "visualParseTree": true
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting this error:

[image: Error when I try to debug]

How should I launch and debug my parser using vscode ?

Comment: Since you engaged the original developer already, https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/issues/233, you might wait for an answer there. Note that so many similar bug reports remain opened on GitHub, not a very good sign.

Answer (score -1):

The generated syntax files (Like mmmTable.interp) should be in the .antlr directory, which is at the same level as the file mmmTable.g4.